# Warning:Instantiation depth might indicate recursion in ModelSim

Tags: verilog

I want to implement HA (half Adder), and I have a problem.  When I click simulate, it displays this warning:

> Warning: Instantiation depth of '/TM_HA/HA/HA/HA .....This might
>   indicate a recursive instantiation.

I don't know what's going on.

HA.v

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module HA(a,b,c,sum,cout);
 input a,b,c;
 output sum,cout;

 wire e1,e2,e3;

 xor(e1,a,b);
 and(e2,a,b);
 and(e3,e1,c);

 xor(sum,e1,c);
 or(cout,e3,e2);

endmodule
```

TM_HA.v

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module TM_HA;
  reg A,B,Cin;
  wire Sum,Cout;

TM_HA HA(.a(A), .b(B), .c(Cin), .sum(Sum), .cout(Cout));

parameter t = 200;
initial
  begin
  #(2*t)
  A = 1'b0;
  B = 1'b0;
  Cin = 1'b0;

  #t
  A = 1'b0;
  B = 1'b0;
  Cin = 1'b1;
  ....
  #t
  $stop;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the warning ModelSim is giving you: you are performing a recursive instantiation. Lets have a look at the first couple of lines of your `TM_HA` module:

```
module TM_HA;
  reg A,B,Cin;
  wire Sum,Cout;

TM_HA HA(.a(A), .b(B), .c(Cin), .sum(Sum), .cout(Cout));
```

*Within* the module `TM_HA`, you are creating an instance called `HA`of the parent module `TM_HA`. This is a recursive call, since that instance will again create another instance of `TM_HA`.

To actually instantiate your `HA` module, you should do (something like) this:

```
HA HA_inst (.a(A), .b(B), .c(Cin), .sum(Sum), .cout(Cout));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you warning says, you have a *recursive instantiation*. This line

```
TM_HA HA(.a(A), .b(B), .c(Cin), .sum(Sum), .cout(Cout));
```

inside module `TM_HA` means

> instantiate module `TM_HA` and give it the *instance name* `HA`.

As that line is inside module `TM_HA`, you are instantiating module `TM_HA` inside itself - a recursive instantiation. At some point, between zero and infinity levels of hierarchy, you simulator gives up.